# Is it possible to connect a Processing sketch to more than one Arduino?

Tags: bluetooth, connection, arduino, wifi, processing

I want to make a group of Arduino robot all of them controlled by a Processing sketch on my computer and  i just want to know if its possible to connect, with wi-fi or bluetooth its the same, more than one Arduino to a Processing sketch.

Answer (score 0):

There is possible to connect more than one arduino in single processing sketch.
Use arduino object array will help you.